# JavaFX Polygon/Polyline Horizontal Sections Disappear

Tags: java, javafx

I'm drawing a simple face in JavaFX. I'm drawing a nose in the shape of a triangle, and one side of the triangle does not render for some reason. (Here's a [link to a picture of the issue](http://mcclurg.co/screenshot.png).)

I searched this site and Google for questions about this, but I cannot find any answers.

I am running this on a Mac with El Capitan, but I can't find any evidence that there is an issue with JavaFX on OS X 10.11.

Below is my code. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is it something else?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

public class SmileyFace extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        // Code for creating head, eyes and mouth go here

        Polygon nose = new Polygon();
        pane.getChildren().add(nose);
        nose.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        nose.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        ObservableList<Double> list = nose.getPoints();
        list.add(150.0);
        list.add(130.0);
        list.add(180.0);
        list.add(200.0);
        list.add(120.0);
        list.add(200.0);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Smiley Face");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me... On the other hand I'm not using OS X...

Comment: Works for me too and I do have a MacBook Pro Retina.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. There must just be something wrong with my computer.